# Save Glide image onClick in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm showing images from the server with RecyclerView. When a user clicks in RecyclerView item it open with ViewPager and FullImage fragment. There is a button that user can save that image.

For now, when user click on a button, I get the image position and save it with another glide request like this -

```
GlideApp.with(container.getContext())
    .asBitmap()
    .load(image.getUrl())
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
               // I want here the trigger option. When user click btn
              // saveImage(resource, image.getTitle());
                        imageViewPreview.setImageBitmap(resource);
            }
});
```

It takes time and data cause it sending another req. I want that when a user clicks on a button, It should save from that original Glide resource. Now how can I trigger that option?

```
GlideApp.with(container.getContext())
    .asBitmap()
    .load(image.getUrl())
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
               // I want here the trigger option. When user click btn
              // saveImage(resource, image.getTitle());
                        imageViewPreview.setImageBitmap(resource);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global `Bitmap` variable, and after first load (when user switch to the current picture) set that bitmap. So, `onResourceReady` you will do something like `currentBitmap = resource`.

Eventually, if you are on the ViewPager, you can get the image based on current position using `getAdapterPosition();` (which I suppose you already do)

Comment: I thought about this. So there's no any other option ?